# Best curve fitting

Tags: least-squares, fast-fourier-transform, python

In general I would like to know the advanced curve fitting algorithms to fit a curved profile from the given set of point coordinates.
would be helpful if any insights on what is the algorithm used in commercial CAD software ( Solidworks, unigraphics and catia )and do we have any python subroutines for the same. I would need this to solve in FEm software.

Comment: There are incredibly many approaches to fit curves. Many of the more or less basic ones you can read on wikipedia, mathworld, courses or other questions here on math.SE et.c. Many softwares are proprietary and the algorithms used are not public so it is rather difficult to answer. Maybe if you can specify what problem you have we can help hinting of some suitable algorithm.

Comment: Thank you....I would like to fit a curve in Fnite element software given nodes/keypoints. The curve looks similar to aerofoil cross secton